# How do I display a dynamic list of all document libraries in a site?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, web-part, document-library, content-query-web-part

In the middle of setting up a 2013 site and am bumping into usability issues with a couple sites that will have 20k+ documents. I know Microsoft has the 5k limit on lists and libraries so I have broke these larger doc groups into smaller document libraries.

My issue is I need to display a page on the site with a dynamic list of the names of these libraries.  My first thought was the content query web part but I can't figure out how to configure it to do what I want. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Instead of different libraries you should have created indexed columns and list views.

Comment: That works for displaying the documents but not for breaking security down on different folders within the library. I think there are a couple other usage limitations that occur over the 5k mark but the securities one is the biggest issue for me.

Comment: For anyone viewing this question, note that the 5,000 limit has nothing to do with how many documents can be stored in a single library. (That number is 30 million!).  Rather, the limit is how many documents can be shown at once in a view of the library.  If you use folders in your library, the 5,000 limit applies to how many documents you can have in a folder and still see all the documents in the folder.

Answer (score 1):

I do recommend using a content search web part and configure it to return only Document library. your query text should look something like that:

[image]

```
Note:make sure to change the Path to reflect the address of your site collection
```

Comment: Couple of follow ups on this.

How would you remove the Site Name that appears preceding the Library name in the list that is shown?

Also, what would the additional statement on the query look like to exclude certain libraries with something identifiable in the name?