# Sharepoint Online - How to set Document Library search to search all doc libraries?

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, search, document

I'm trying to change the search behavior for the search box within a document library.  I'd like this search box to search the entire sharepoint site, not just the current document library I'm viewing.

[image]

Similar to the search functionality seen when using the home page search.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

It's a good idea, but it's **not doable** in the document library Search box!

The `Search box` is only scoped for the current document library contents and can't be reconfigured to search for other document libraries.

Perhaps the `Content Search web part` can help you to control the search scope.

**For more details about `Content Search web part` check**

- [Configure a Content Search Web Part in SharePoint](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/configure-a-content-search-web-part-in-sharepoint-0dc16de1-dbe4-462b-babb-bf8338c36c9a)
- [How do I display a dynamic list of all document libraries in a site?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/181919/how-do-i-display-a-dynamic-list-of-all-document-libraries-in-a-site)

Answer (score 1):

There is no currently way to change this , from your screenshot , you may using new experience for this document library , the search box is similar with "find a file" in classic experience . Since you are searching within specific document library, you will only get results that are documents and not other content located on your site .

The workaround you can use classic experience for this document library , situated in the top right corner you can search all content in your entire site .

https://beinsp.wordpress.com/2016/09/27/search-for-files-in-sharepoint-online/
https://sharepointmaven.com/2-ways-to-search-for-files-in-sharepoint/